# A sequence of polynomial is irreducible or not under applied condition

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which of the following statement is/are true for the following  equation, where $n$ is a positive integer?

$$f_{n}(x)=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1$$

> - $f_{n}(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q(x)}$ for every positive integer $n$
> - $f_{p}(x)$ is irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q(x)}$ for every prime number $p$
> - $f_{p}(x^{p{^{C-1}}}$) is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ for every prime $p$ and every positive integer $c$.
> - $f_{p^{C}}(x)$ is an irreduciblepolynomial in $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ for every positive integer $c$

First option is true only when n is prime number so 1st option is wrong,second option is true because it become a cyclotomic polynomial which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$(x).4th option can be discarded by taking example of $p=2$ and $c=2$, now i am stuck on 3rd option plz help

Comment: case 3 is a cyclotomic polynomial too.

Comment: Can you please explain it.

Comment: It's the $p^c$-th cyclotomic polynomial.

Comment: But still i want full explanation, can you please provide any link or pdf something?